# SQL - Compare Values from Ajax array and DELETE them IF NOT in TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables

```
TABLE 1

|  WORD |
_________
| word1 |
| word2 |
| word3 |

TABLE 2

|  ID ||  WORD |
__________________
| ID1 || word1 |
| ID1 || word2 |
| ID2 || word1 |
| ID2 || word3 |
| ID2 || word2 |
| ID3 || word2 |
| ID3 || word4 |
| ID4 || word5 |
| ID5 || word5 |
```

I do a query :

```
SELECT WORD, count(WORD)
FROM TABLE 2 
WHERE WORD in ('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word7', 'word8')
GROUP BY WORD
```

It returns me a table like this :

```
|  WORD ||  COUNT(WORD) |
_________________________
| word1 ||      2        |
| word2 ||      3        |
| word3 ||      1        |
```

But what I need is the inverse of that ...I need to have an array with 'word7' and 'word8' (all matches with num_rows = 0...)

And when I have this result, I want to use them for DELETE them in TABLE 1

I Tried that but i'm not on the right way...

```
if(mysql_num_rows($mots_cles_count) == 0) {
            mysqli_query($BDD_connect, "DELETE FROM TABLE 1 WHERE (WORD) IN ('word7'), ('word8');
        }
```

---

---

**EDIT : Compare Values from Ajax array and DELETE them IF NOT in TABLE**

---

---

My code has evolved...

With a POST METHOD `$tab_tuto_sauvegarde = $_POST['tableau_valeurs_modifiees'];` a Ajax request returns to me this informations :

```
[Mots_cles_supprimes] => Array
    (
        [0] => jambon
        [1] => rap
        [2] => tomate
    )
```

For each `[index]` of `tableau_valeurs_modifiees.['Mots_cles_supprimes']` (here : "jambon", "rap" and "tomate") compare these words to the `TABLE 2` and if not yet in this `TABLE 2`, DELETE them in the `TABLE 1`

I think I have the end of the code (DELETE in the `TABLE 1`)but it miss me the condition `IF` this word `is not in TABLE 1`

```
    $stmt_mot_a_sup = mysqli_prepare($BDD_connect, "DELETE FROM Mots_cles SET mots_cles = ? ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_mot_a_sup, "s", $mot_a_sup);
    foreach ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'] as $Mots_cles_supprimes) {
        $mot_a_sup = $Mots_cles_supprimes;
        mysqli_execute($stmt_mot_a_sup);
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong with WHERE NOT IN (...)?

Comment: you can't mix mysql_* and mysqli_* functions. The mysql_* functions are deprecated, so please use mysqli or PDO. That said: Do you want to delete those words from table1 that haven't got a corresponding row in table2?

Comment: @VMai yes I want to delete words in table 1 that no more in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to delete the parent rows with no corresponding child rows, in which case you can do something like this:

```
delete from table1
where not exists (
  select null from table2 where table2.word = table1.word
)
```

Comment: I tried but some problems exit... erreur in sql #1064

Comment: it works but for a bigger databases, this should be optimized. In a near future, TABLE 1 and TABLE 2 will have thousands words in database... and at each request (thousands by hours may be more...) I can't use computer server to compare all TABLE 1 and all TABLE 2 ... That's why I just need to compare words from Ajax Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
DELETE FROM 
    table1
LEFT JOIN 
    table2
ON 
    table1.word = table2.word
WHERE
   table2.word IS NULL
```